# Design pattern to set certain fields in object based on enum values

Tags: java, scala, design-patterns

So basically what I want to do is fill/not fill certain fields in an object based off a list of enums.

For example the object in question:

```
case class Car(brand: String,
              model: String,
              wheels: Int,
              airbags: Boolean,
              seats: Int,
               cruiseControl: Boolean,
               photo: String,
               parkingAssist: Boolean)
```

This is the full object, and depending on list of Java enum types I want to set certain fields. Also combinations are possible and they might overlap.

```
enum CarType {
  BASIC_CAR,
  LUXURY_CAR,
  SAFE_CAR,
  PICTURE_CAR
}
```

So basically depending on the CarType I would like to set certain fields of Car. For example:

> BASIC_CAR need to se brand, model, wheels and seats.
>
> LUXURY_CAR need to set brand, model, cruiseControl and parkingAssist
>
> SAFE_CAR need to set airbags
>
> PICTURE_CAR need to set parkingAssist

So I will receive a list of these enums and then need to create the object. For example I will have one object with BASIC_CAR, LUXURY_CAR, SAFE_CAR which means the object I create will have to have all fields except parkingAssist.

So in the end, the enums relate to certain field and basically on the (combination of) enums I require to set certain fields in the object. What would be a good design for this?

Comment: You can't "not fill" a field in an object, they all have to be there. Consider using `Option` to hold values that might or might not be available. And where do the values for the selected fields come from?

Comment: And there is something you can do with enums https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html

Comment: Why not creating an ADT instead? Instead of having the type of cars as a value, have it as a type. Create different types of cars.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the Decorator pattern to solve this problem.
Check out this web site to get an example: 
https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/decorator

I edit my post for being more specific, I mean something like this:

```java
public interface Car {

    public void assemble();
}

public class BasicCar implements Car {

    @Override
    public void assemble() {
        //set basic car:  brand, model, wheels and seats.
    }

}

public class CarDecorator implements Car {

    protected Car car;

    public CarDecorator(Car c){
        this.car=c;
    }

    @Override
    public void assemble() {
        this.car.assemble();
    }

}

public class LuxuryCar extends CarDecorator {

    public LuxuryCar(Car c) {
        super(c);
    }

    @Override
    public void assemble(){
        super.assemble();
        //add especial fields for luxury car or override values from basic car
    }
}
```

and depending on the Enum value you can instanciate different classes: new LuxuryCar(), new SportCar()

Comment: Could you be more specific about how you would use the decorator pattern to do this?

Comment: As @azernik said above, it is important to describe how your answer solves the problem, and for a code question, the best way to do this is to provide at least some code in your answer, showing a (possibly simplified) implementation that the asker can work with.

Comment: A negative vote for not being specific... I think it's not to much friendly with new contributors